# retrieve data from database mysql not working

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

Hi i am using the html dropdown's onchange event using ajax

In the code i am using, should get the address column value when i change the 
drop down.

but it is not working.What may have gone wrong?

here is the code

```
<html>
<head>
  <script>
     function showUser( str ) {
        if ( str == "" ) {
           document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
           return;
        }
        if ( window.XMLHttpRequest ) {
           // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
           xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
           // code for IE6, IE5
           xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
           if ( xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
               document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
           }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "getuser.php?q=" + str, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
     }
   </script>
</head>
<body>

<form>    
  <?php
     mysql_connect('localhost', 'tiger', 'tiger');
     mysql_select_db('theaterdb');
     $sql = "select theater_name from theater;";
     $result = mysql_query($sql);
     echo "<select name='theater_name' id='course' onchange='showUser(this.value);'>";
     while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
        echo "<option value='" . $row['theater_name'] ."'>" . $row['theater_name']. "</option>";
     }
     echo "</select>";
?>

</form>

<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Info</b></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code for getuser.php

```
<?php
   $q = $_GET["q"];
   $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "tiger", "tiger", "theaterdb");
   if ( !$con ) {
      die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error( $con ) );
   }

   mysqli_select_db( $con );
   $sql = "SELECT address FROM theater WHERE theater_name = '".$q."'";

   $result = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );

   echo "<table border='1'>
     <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
     </tr>";

     while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ) {
       echo "<tr>";
          echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
       echo "</tr>";
    }
  echo "</table>";
  mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: You getting something in `$result`? `print_r($result)`

And `$q`? `echo $q`

Comment: Start by explaining "Not working"

Comment: make sure that the username and password provided are correct

Comment: @Shadowfax no i am not getting those values when i print

Comment: Are you getting the value to `str` before `xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);` line

Comment: I think Your DB connection is wrong.$con = mysql_connect('localhost', 'tiger', 'tiger');
mysql_select_db('theaterdb',$con);

Comment: @Shadowfax Yes i tried alerting that value... i am getting the value to str;

Comment: Is your file `getuser.php` in the same directory as your html code?

Comment: start from running directly your queries against the database...

Comment: The problem is not the database, he's not even getting the value `$q=$_GET["q"];`; some issue while he post the variable to other file

Comment: @Shadowfax yes it is in same directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've tweaked your files slightly, you shouldn't be using mysql_ or the mysqli_ functions any more, just don't... And you certainly shouldn't be using mysql function in one file and mysqli functions in the other... I've switched them over to use PDO, you're script now isn't susceptible to SQL injection, and as far as I can tell it works just fine.

index.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
            function showUser(str) {
                if(str=="") {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
                    return;
                }

                if(window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
                } else {
                    xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }

                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                    if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
                        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("GET","getuser.php?q="+str,true);
                xmlhttp.send();
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <form>
        <?php
        try {
            $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
        }

        $sql = "SELECT theater_name FROM theater;";

        $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
        $sth->execute();

        echo "<select name='theater_name' id='course' onchange='showUser(this.value);'>";

        while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            echo "<option value='" . $row['theater_name'] ."'>" . $row['theater_name']. "</option>";
        }
        echo "</select>";
        ?>
        </form>
        <br>
        <div id="txtHint"><b>Info</b></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

getuser.php

```
<?php
$q = strtolower(trim($_GET["q"]));

try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=theaterdb;host=localhost','tiger','tiger');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

$sql = 'SELECT address FROM theater WHERE LOWER(theater_name) = :q';

$sth = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$sth->bindValue(':q', $q);
$sth->execute();

echo "<table border='1'><tr><th>Firstname</th></tr>";

while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['address'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

$dbh = null;
```

Answer (score -1):

I am unable to understand why have you connected with database in both of php files ?
I would suggest you to visit below link.

http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp